# How can I manually invoke dbus.service.signal decorator?

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to dynamically add signals to a D-Bus service using dbus-python. It provides a decorator for this that works fine if the signal names are known at module load time; however, I don't know what name to export to D-Bus until runtime.

To illustrate the problem, what I'd *like* to do is the moral equivalent of:

```
import dbus
import dbus.service
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

class Event(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.busName = dbus.service.BusName('com.acme.EventManager',
                                            bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self,
                                     self.busName,
                                     '/com/acme/EventManager/' +
                                     self.name)

        self.signame = 'com.acme.EventManager.' + self.name

    # THIS DOES NOT WORK: this decorator is parsed before the Event
    # class, and 'self' wouldn't exist here, anyway...
    @dbus.service.signal(dbus_interface=self.signame, signature='v')
    def emit(self, data):
        print "In %s event, got: %s " % (self.name, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    connect = Event('Connect')
    disconnect = Event('Disconnect')
    loop.run()
```

Not surprisingly, this generates:

```
@dbus.service.signal(dbus_interface=self.signame, signature='v')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I thought I could just dispense with the syntactic sugar provided by the `@` decoration operator and patch Event manually after the class has been defined, something like this:

```
import dbus
import dbus.service
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

class Event(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.busName = dbus.service.BusName('com.acme.EventManager',
                                            bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self,
                                     self.busName,
                                     '/com/acme/EventManager/' +
                                     self.name)

        self.signame = 'com.acme.EventManager.' + self.name

    def emit(self, data):
        print "In %s event, got: %s " % (self.name, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    e1 = Event('Connect')
    e1.emit = dbus.service.signal(dbus_interface=e1.signame,
                              signature='v')(e1.emit)
    loop.run()
```

This runs without errors, but it fails to export the signals to D-Bus. When I run D-Feet, I see the object path `/com/acme/EventManager/Connect` but it has no interface methods aside from `Introspect()`.

To see if I could learn something about what was going on, I examined the value of the function passed to the `dbus.service.signal` decorator in a debugger.  For this typical use case:

```
@dbus.service.signal(dbus_interface='com.acme.foo', signature='v')
def emit(self, data):
    pass
```

the function passed in to the decorator (in the variable `func`) looks like this:

```
>>> func
>>> <function emit at 0x99fbed4>
```

But when I *manually* invoke the decorator function (as in the the `e1.emit =` assignment in the second example above), I see:

```
>>> func
>>> <bound method Event.emit of <__main__.Event at /com/acme/EventManager/Connect at 0x9b3348c>>
```

So... it seems that, for the *normal* use case, `dbus.service.signal` expects to receive a free function---**not** an unbound function, but a function that, for all intents and purposes, looks like it was defined using:

```
def emit():
    pass
```

This behavior is utterly mystifying to me. I've read lots of tutorials on decorators, and thought I understood them pretty well, but I have been stumped on this for *hours*. If this decorator expects to be called with 'raw' function, how can I convert an object method such that I can invoke it manually?

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object), I see that `types.MethodType()` can be used to convert a free function to a bound method. But it seems I need to do the opposite(?)

Comment: If `dbus.service.signal()` returns a decorator that expects to receive an argument which is a function with no arguments of its own, then you simple can't use it to call your `Event.emit()` method. What does the documentation say about (if all else fails read the source code).

Comment: The docs say the decorator should be used to "mark methods of a dbus.service.Object to be exported on the D-Bus" [http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.service-module.html#signal]

Comment: From the docs and the source it looks to me like the decorator `dbus.service.signal()` returns does handle methods with arguments of their own just fine. I think the problem with doing it manually is that you're passing that decorator `e1.emit` which is a bound method but it's expecting an unbound method because it's actually a _method_ decorator. To do it manually you'd have to pass it `Event.emit` instead of `e1.emit`, but of course that won't work with the way you've defined the `Event` class. To do what you want I think you're going to need to write a class decorator or metaclass.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but I'm afraid I'm unable to convert them into a solution. It isn't at all obvious to me why passing ``Event.emit`` won't work. In fact, it's one of the things I tried. This, too, runs without errors, but doesn't work correctly (the object path isn't even registered with D-Bus in this case). I hope that including a short, complete program  in my question will allow someone to post an answer with a working solution.

Comment: Sorry, to post a complete working solution would require installing the `D-Bus` package which I am not interested in doing. When you tried using `dbus.service.signal()` with `Event.emit`, what did you use for the `dbus_interface` argument? The problem is in the design of your `Event` class. The decorator is meant to be used in cases of separate subclasses of `dbus.service.Object`, for example see [this](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.service.Object-class.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to do what you want is by using a factory function — however the following is untested because I don't have the D-Bus module installed.

The root of the problem is you're attempting to use a decorator at class definition time that requires data which isn't being provided until instances of that class are created. One workaround for that is to define the class inside a function and use [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) so the data is available when needed. Note that the factory function returns *instances* of the class created, not the class itself, although it could if desired.

```
import dbus
import dbus.service
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def event_factory(event_name):
    class Event(dbus.service.Object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.busName = dbus.service.BusName('com.acme.EventManager',
                                                bus=dbus.SessionBus())
            dbus.service.Object.__init__(self,
                                         self.busName,
                                         '/com/acme/EventManager/'+event_name)

        @dbus.service.signal(dbus_interface='com.acme.EventManager.'+event_name,
                             signature='v')
        def emit(self, data):
            print "In %s event, got: %s " % (event_name, data)

    return Event() # return an instance of the class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    connect = event_factory('Connect')
    disconnect = event_factory('Disconnect')
    loop.run()
```

Comment: LOL, I _just_ woke up with that same idea. Your solution works perfectly for my current purposes.  Thanks for framing it in terms of a _factory function_ and a _closure_, concepts I can readily understand. One undesirable aspect of doing it this way is that the class definition is parsed/stored every time ``event_factory()`` is called, but I hardly care for this rough prototype. If I figure out a way to do it by invoking the decorator manually, I'll post it as an alternate solution.

Comment: If you made the function return the class, effectively making it a class factory (sort of like a C++ template), then you might be able to avoid the overhead of creating the class more than once. However if you only want to create a single instance of one, might as well do it this way. On the other hand being just a class factory means a metaclass could be used.